# Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to IBM remote MQ and I am facing this System.DllNotFoundException error . I built a simple console application using C# and wrote MQ connection code .

My code

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using IBM.WMQ;
   using System.Diagnostics;

   namespace MQMessageSender
   {
       public class MQTest
       {
            public static void Main()
            {

              ConnectMQ();
            }

             public  static int ConnectMQ()
             {
                 MQQueueManager queueManager;
                 MQQueue queue;
                 MQMessage queueMessage;
                 MQPutMessageOptions queuePutMessageOptions;
                 MQGetMessageOptions queueGetMessageOptions;


                 string QueueName;
                 string QueueManagerName;
                 string ChannelInfo;
                 string channelName;
                 string PortNumber;
                 string transportType;
                 string connectionName;
                 string message;

                 QueueManagerName = "******";
                 QueueName = "********";
                 ChannelInfo = "********/TCP/********(****)";
                 PortNumber = "****";


                 char[] separator = { '/' };
                 string[] ChannelParams;
                 ChannelParams = ChannelInfo.Split(separator);
                 channelName = ChannelInfo;
                 transportType = ChannelParams[1];
                 connectionName = ChannelParams[2];

                 String strReturn = "";


                 try
                 {
                    queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName,
                    channelName, connectionName);
                    strReturn = "Connected Successfully";
                 }
                 catch (MQException exp)
                 {
                     strReturn = "Exception: " + exp.Message;
                 }
                  Console.WriteLine(strReturn);
                  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
                  Console.ReadLine();
                  return 0;

              }
        }

   }
```

Can anyone help me with this . Mostly try block is generating this error . Any kind of information will help . Please help . Error screenshot is attached .

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory. It means it is looking in C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin\ for the required mqdc.dll file and not finding it. Either copy that dll over to that location or change your project file so that it gives a hint path to where you are storing this dll file.

Comment: thanks for reply :) . Can you tell me mqdc.dll is realted to IBM MQ? cause to connect IBM MQ amqmdnet.dll is required .

Comment: I have not worked with that library personally, but as the program is looking in IBM\MQ\bin for this .dll, I'd say it is related.

Comment: ok . thanks @RyanWilson

Comment: You're welcome. Have a good day.

Comment: Looks like a 32/64 bit issue. Which version of IBM MQ did you install and with what configuration did you build your project?

Comment: If you are using managed mode type of connection then only having amqmdnet.dll should be sufficient. If you are using unmanaged mode then a IBM MQ Client installation is required,because unmanaged mode uses the underlying IBM MQ C client to establish a connection to the queue manager

Comment: @CodeCaster I am using version 9.0.0.0 IBM MQ and it's installed into program files means it's 64 bit . I am using visual studio 32 bit . this is causing problem?

Comment: @subbaraoc I can connect to remote MQ using IBM MQ user interface and it shows that connection type is client

Comment: By default MQ.NET uses unmanaged(client) transport mode.If you want to use just amqmdnet.dll then you will have to use managed mode of connection.To set the transport property you will have to use the Hashtable to set the connection properties. Look  at the samples located at "&INSTALLPATH&\Tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base will give you some idea about setting at the Transport mode.

Comment: @subbaraoc is there any document or links regarding this unmanaged mode transport property .. or do i need to uninstall IBM MQ and then reinstall IBM MQ into managed mode? Can you help me on this . I searched through net but haven't found too much on it

Comment: It is just a property that you have to set and it has nothing to do with the installation. Following is the link on the MQ .NET classes
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029260_.html

Following link talks about how to set the transport property and which dll is used when a particular transport mode is used

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029480_.html

Comment: @subbaraoc thank you so much :) . these links are really helpful. specially this link &INSTALLPATH&\Tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base

Comment: @saha.jan You're welcome.